# Emulate break statement in ForEach function

Tags: c#, lambda

This is more of a hypothetical question as I am using .NET 3.5 more and more along with lambda expressions and anonymous delegates.  Take this simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<int> numList = new List<int>(int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15 });

   numList.ForEach(i =>
   {
       if (i % 2 == 1)
           Console.Write(i);
       else
           return;
   });

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will produce the output:

> 13579111315

Of course, what I'd really like it to do is to stop executing the ForEach function after 12, and not print 13 or 15.  In a traditional foreach construct, you would have a break (instead of the return in my example), and the loop would end. However, a break is illegal in this case.  You get the following message:

> No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue

Is there a construct I could easily employ here to get the desired result, or is it just better to use a standard foreach loop in this case if you don't intend to actually run the desired code on every single member of a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a standard `foreach` loop. This is almost always simpler and less confusing than using a lambda expression - you don't get confusion over captured variables etc.

You may wish to read [Eric Lippert's post on this as well](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

`List<T>.ForEach` is useful if you've been handed a delegate and you just want to execute it on each element in the list - but otherwise I'd stick with the normal language feature.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a feeling this was the answer, but was curious what others thought. Sometimes its as if Lambdas are really over used over more "traditional" sequences.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I know what you mean. There is a temptation to use them everywhere...

Comment: Interestingly, this is also an issue when using .NET parallel foreach constructs, which use delegates in much the same way. Their solution was to add a LoopState mechanism. You can see an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: @LBushkin - Thanks for the added info... I hadn't thought of the parallel extensions when I wrote my question, but the same problem would definitely apply.